# how to copy multiple tables from azure sql to gen2 using databricks notebook in adf

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to capy multiple tables from azure sql to gen2 using databricks notebook in adf

to copy multiple tables from azuresql to gen2 is it possible? And How?
I tried many times but isnt working, can anyone share the answer

Comment: Could you please provide the approach what you have tried and blockage what you got?

Comment: You can copy the tables from Azure SQL database to ADLS gen2 using copy activity in ADF without using Databricks notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy multiple tables from Azure SQl database to ADLS Gen 2 account by using copy activity in azure data factory without using Databricks notebook. You can below procedure:

Perform look up activity to get the tables list in database. Select sql data set and select query option and enter below query

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

after successful of lookup connect for each item and add `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`  as dynamic content in item tab. go to activities of foreach and select copy activity,Create two sql linked services one for lookup activity and one for source and adls gen2 linked service and create sql data set with linked service select the sql dataset as source and create two parameters named Schema and tableName and given below values:

```
schema: @item().TABLE_SCHEMA
tableName: @item().TABLE_NAME
```

I passed above parameters as directory of table in copy activity source dataset as mentioned below:

```
Table: @dataset.schema.@dataset.table
```

Create ADLS delimited dataset with created linked service and select the ADLS data set as data source.

[image]

Debug the pipeline it run successfully.

[image]

Those table save in ADLS successfully.

[image]

Pipeline Json:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value\n",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".csv"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "Schema": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_SCHEMA",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "tableName": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_NAME",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```